# Kotlin spread operator failing to convert array into vararg

Tags: kotlin, operators, charts4j

I'm trying to use the charts4j library with kotlin, but I'm having issues creating a Data object, as it wants either `double...` or `List<? extends Number>` as parameters. I can't create a list of `? extends Number` as it doesn't seem to like `out Number` as a type, and for some reason, it fails to accept the spread operator as well. I don't really understand why this is happening, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
val list = ArrayList<Double>()

for (i in 1..100) {
    println(i)
    list.add(i.toDouble())
}

val plot: Plot = Plots.newPlot(Data.newData(*list.toTypedArray()))
val chart: LineChart = GCharts.newLineChart(plot)
val url: String = chart.toURLString()

print(url)
```

Comment: have you tried the simplest thing and just do: `Plots.newPlot(Data.newData(list))`? I just did, and it works just fine.

Comment: facepalm, I completely overlooked that method. thanks a lot, and apologies for the dumb question.

Comment: And the reason it didn't work was you were converting it to an `Array<Double>` instead of a `DoubleArray`. The distinction is important to Java code because it is the difference between `Double[]` and `double[]`. The solution would be to use `toDoubleArray()` instead of `toTypedArray()`.